# Swift - Speech to text and save audio file

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, swift4

I'm working on the app which utilizes speech to text feature of iOS.
I found really nice sample app from apple: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SpeakToMe/Introduction/Intro.html

This app is using live: SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest function and automatically transcribes speech to text. 
Also, I found many tutorials which transcribing audio file to text.

But I need something different, I want live text to speech feature (just as sample app above) and I need to save audio file. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the technique described in [Saving Recorded Audio (Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361991/saving-recorded-audio-swift). Basically, set up an `AVAudioRecorder` like this and then hook it up with your returned audio output to save the clip.

```
func setupRecorder() {


    let recordSettings : [String : AnyObject] =
    [
        AVFormatIDKey: NSNumber(unsignedInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQuality.Max.rawValue as NSNumber,
        AVEncoderBitRateKey : 320000 as NSNumber,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2 as NSNumber,
        AVSampleRateKey : 44100.0 as NSNumber
    ]

    do {

      try   soundRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: getFileURL(), settings: recordSettings)
            soundRecorder.delegate = self
            soundRecorder.prepareToRecord()

    } catch {

        print(error)
    }


}

func getCacheDirectory() -> String {

    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true) 

    return paths[0]

}

func getFileURL() -> NSURL{

    let path  = getCacheDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)

    let filePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)

    return filePath
}

func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(recorder: AVAudioRecorder, successfully flag: Bool) {
    PlayButton.enabled = true
    recordedAudio = RecordedAudio()
    recordedAudio.filePathUrl = recorder.url
    recordedAudio.title = recorder.url.lastPathComponent
    print(recordedAudio.title)
}
```

Comment: can you suggest how to hook it up in this file: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SpeakToMe/Listings/SpeakToMe_ViewController_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017110-SpeakToMe_ViewController_swift-DontLinkElementID_6

Comment: How can I hook it up in 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SpeakToMe/Listings/SpeakToMe_ViewController_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017110-SpeakToMe_ViewController_swift-DontLinkElementID_6